# Change default selected country and province in Magento

Tags: select, magento

I need to have either the only country viewed or the default country to be Canada and more specifically british columbia when choosing an address in Magento. What would be needed to make this change?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting the country and locale should take care of this for you.

```
Admin -> System Configuration -> General -> Countries options -> Default country 
Admin -> System Configuration -> General -> Locale options -> Locale
```

Comment: This is fine for the country but it does not provide a way to set a default value for the state/province.

Comment: yep. locale != state :) anyone knows how to set default state?